# cURL or SSL problems, how to solve?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, curl

I keep getting this error:

```
No cURL data returned for https://XXX.XXXX.XXX:XXXX [0] SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I am not sure, or I could say, I dont know what is this problem. And how to solve this? Please help!

Answer (score 10):

The error is fairly clear. Essentially what is happening is that the cert on the remote end is either self signed, or signed by an authority that wget isn't recognizing. You can pass the following command while invoking wget to get it to ignore cert errors:

```
--no-check-certificate
```

Comment: You mean put this line on m curl call? I am using php and very new to curl, could you explain and if possible show some sample code??

Comment: Well, this is merely a workaround and no real solution. If you are using ssl protected connections you must check these certificates and NOT just disable the checks.. 

One could use extremly outdated and broken certs and you would not recognize this with not using the cert check! Otherwise we could change back to selfsigned certs or non protected connections if we were so lazy not to use the cert checks.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the *--insecure* option to bypass SSL verification

Comment: No, --insecure is for fools, hence the name. If you're using SSL/HTTPS, you probably do NOT want insecure transactions.

Comment: Is it foolish to test a hosting transfer before DNS changes `SSL: certificate subject name 'www.mysite.co.nz' does not match target host name '123.4.5.6'`

Answer (score 5):

### curl -k

> curl -k https://scottlinux.com

source: [scottlinux.com/curl-ignore-ssl-certificate-warnings/](http://scottlinux.com/2012/02/14/curl-ignore-ssl-certificate-warnings/)

Answer (score 1):

Curl is objecting to the SSL certificate provided by the HTTPS server.  Assuming the cert is valid in the first place, you may need to add the authorizing servers to the certificate chain in your curl-ca-bundle.crt.

Comment: I already added to my server, now, how do I chain in my curl-ca-bundle.crt? Btw, I am using php

Answer (score 0):

check this question on stackoverflow.com

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521418/reading-ssl-page-with-curl-php